# Makefileにヘッダーファイルとcファイルを追加する方法について

Tags: gcc, makefile

現在,dma_simple.hとdma_simple.cをyolov3 darknetのMakefileに入れてビルドしようと考えていますが、どこに追加すればいいでしょうか？

Makefile

```
GPU=0
CUDNN=0
OPENCV=0
OPENMP=0
DEBUG=0

ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
      -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
      -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] \
      -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]
#      -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] \ This one is deprecated?

# This is what I use, uncomment if you know your arch and want to specify
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52

VPATH=./src/:./examples
SLIB=libdarknet.so
ALIB=libdarknet.a
EXEC=darknet
OBJDIR=./obj/

CC=gcc
CPP=g++
NVCC=nvcc 
AR=ar
ARFLAGS=rcs
OPTS=-Ofast
LDFLAGS= -lm -pthread 
COMMON= -Iinclude/ -Isrc/
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC

ifeq ($(OPENMP), 1) 
CFLAGS+= -fopenmp
endif

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1) 
OPTS=-O0 -g
endif

CFLAGS+=$(OPTS)

ifeq ($(OPENCV), 1) 
COMMON+= -DOPENCV
CFLAGS+= -DOPENCV
LDFLAGS+= `pkg-config --libs opencv` -lstdc++
COMMON+= `pkg-config --cflags opencv` 
endif

ifeq ($(GPU), 1) 
COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
CFLAGS+= -DGPU
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
endif

ifeq ($(CUDNN), 1) 
COMMON+= -DCUDNN 
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN
LDFLAGS+= -lcudnn
endif

OBJ=gemm.o utils.o cuda.o deconvolutional_layer.o convolutional_layer.o list.o image.o activations.o im2col.o col2im.o blas.o crop_layer.o dropout_layer.o maxpool_layer.o softmax_layer.o data.o matrix.o network.o connected_layer.o cost_layer.o parser.o option_list.o detection_layer.o route_layer.o upsample_layer.o box.o normalization_layer.o avgpool_layer.o layer.o local_layer.o shortcut_layer.o logistic_layer.o activation_layer.o rnn_layer.o gru_layer.o crnn_layer.o demo.o batchnorm_layer.o region_layer.o reorg_layer.o tree.o  lstm_layer.o l2norm_layer.o yolo_layer.o iseg_layer.o image_opencv.o
EXECOBJA=captcha.o lsd.o super.o art.o tag.o cifar.o go.o rnn.o segmenter.o regressor.o classifier.o coco.o yolo.o detector.o nightmare.o instance-segmenter.o darknet.o
ifeq ($(GPU), 1) 
LDFLAGS+= -lstdc++ 
OBJ+=convolutional_kernels.o deconvolutional_kernels.o activation_kernels.o im2col_kernels.o col2im_kernels.o blas_kernels.o crop_layer_kernels.o dropout_layer_kernels.o maxpool_layer_kernels.o avgpool_layer_kernels.o
endif

EXECOBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(EXECOBJA))
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJ))
DEPS = $(wildcard src/*.h) Makefile include/darknet.h

all: obj backup results $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC)
#all: obj  results $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC)


$(EXEC): $(EXECOBJ) $(ALIB)
    $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(ALIB)

$(ALIB): $(OBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

$(SLIB): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CPP) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
    $(NVCC) $(ARCH) $(COMMON) --compiler-options "$(CFLAGS)" -c $< -o $@

obj:
    mkdir -p obj
backup:
    mkdir -p backup
results:
    mkdir -p results

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC) $(EXECOBJ) $(OBJDIR)/*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dma_simple.hとdma_simple.cをsrcディレクトリに追加して、

OBJ=gemm.o utils.o cuda.o deconvolutional_layer.o ... 行の後に、

OBJ+=dma_simple.o

を追加してみてください。

Comment: [Makefileでwarningが起こる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60855/makefile%e3%81%a7warning%e3%81%8c%e8%b5%b7%e3%81%93%e3%82%8b)追加できましたが、warningが出てしまいました。

Comment: 無事にdma_simple.cをビルドすることができた、ということですよね?? warningが出てしまいました、と言われると折角回答したのに悪い事をしたみたいな気持ちになりますw

Comment: kzzさんの回答のおかげでビルドできました。違うところでwaringが出たので別で質問をしました。気を悪くしてしまって申し訳ありません。

Comment: 解決したということであれば回答を承認することができますので、ご検討くださいませ。参考：[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)